# How to break up a huge service.cs file into multiple smaller services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a service defined like this:

```
public class MentorService : IMentorService
{
    private readonly Func<MentorContext> _dbFactory;

    public MentorService(string connectionString)
    {
        this._dbFactory = () => new MentorContext(connectionString);
    }

    public MentorService()
    {
        this._dbFactory = () => new MentorContext();
    }

    public MentorContext CreateContext()
    {
        return _dbFactory.Invoke();
    }

    public IList<User> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var db = CreateContext())
        {
            return db.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
    // etc etc
 }
```

Within my API controllers, I have the following:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{

    private readonly IMentorService _mentorService;

    public UserController()
    {
        _mentorService = new MentorService();
    }
    public UserController(IMentorService mentorService)
    {
        _mentorService = mentorService;
    }
}
```

I'd like to break the service up into sub-services for easier maintenance and testing - something like UserService, BookService, etc.  Then I just want to use a single service in my controllers.

How can this be done?

Comment: ...can you not split related functions into separate classes?.. I'm not 100% sure what you are having trouble with.. can you elaborate?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead How to I break a massive class of functions into subclasses, while still being able to reference only a single class.  I know it's a simple C# question but I don't know the syntax :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a huge fan of factories for this sort of thing.

(Please note, I am assuming you have some sort of DI/IoC setup, considering you have an interface-based example)

Basically, you first split your code into separate classes `UserService`, `BookService`, etc. Once you've done that, you create a factory that creates these services for you. Something like this:

```
public class UserControllerServiceFactory : IUserControllerServiceFactory {
    public IUserService CreateUserService() {
        return _container.Get<IUserService>();
    }

    public IBookService CreateBookService() {
        return _container.Get<IBookService>();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

We use Ninject for our DI/IoC, and prefer to use the Factories extensions for Ninject. This means we don't have to implement the factories ourselves.. we only define the interfaces.

Then you have the factory injected into your controller:

```
public UserController(IUserControllerServiceFactory factory) {
    _factory = factory;
}
```

And then, your Action Methods use the factory to access the services you require:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewAllBooks() {
    return View(_factory.CreateBookService().GetAll());
}
```

etc.

I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: You don't need Ninject.. I was just mentioning that we use the Factories extension for Ninject to do the above automatically for us. The principle is the same.. create a Factory class that creates services for you. Then you _could_ expose the Factory as a property of your MentorService.. although I probably wouldn't do it that way..